# Passing a member function pointer as a parameter? Q&A

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

I'm trying to do something that I thought was pretty simple - passing a queue and a function and having the function be applied for each item in the queue - but I can't get this to compile.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    void doStuff();
    void doStuffOnBars(std::queue<Bar*> &bars, void (*func)(Bar &bar));
    virtual void stuff(Bar &bar) = 0;

    std::queue<Bar*> _bars;
};

void Foo::doStuff()
{
    doStuffOnBars(_bars, stuff);
}

void Foo::doStuffOnBars(std::queue<Bar*> &bars, void (*func)(Bar &bar))
{
    while (!bars.empty())
    {
        func(*bars.front());
        bars.pop();
    }
}
```

`doStuffOnBars(_bars, stuff)` and `doStuffOnBars(_bars, this->stuff)` return C3867.

`doStuffOnBars(_bars, &stuff)` and `doStuffOnBars(_bars, &this->stuff)` return C2276.

`doStuffOnBars(_bars, &(Foo::stuff))` with `void doStuffOnBars(std::queue<Bar*> &bars, void (Foo::*func)(Bar &bar))` returns C2064.

So I'm absolutely out of ideas. All of the examples of function pointers I've seen seem to magically work - I think most of them are in the global scope? Why does this differ with member functions?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to figure it out by myself before I asked it (after a bit of nail-biting and hair-pulling). I'll put up the working code for other people's reference:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    void doStuff();
    void doStuffOnBars(std::queue<Bar*> &bars, void (Foo::*func)(Bar &bar));
    virtual void stuff(Bar &bar) = 0;

    std::queue<Bar*> _bars;
};

void Foo::doStuff()
{
    doStuffOnBars(_bars, stuff);
}

void Foo::doStuffOnBars(std::queue<Bar*> &bars, void (Foo::*func)(Bar &bar))
{
    while (!bars.empty())
    {
        (this->*func)(*bars.front());
        bars.pop();
    }
}
```

The function must be called with `(this->*func)` - the function needs an object reference (`this`) and the function needs to be dereferenced (it is a *pointer* after all). Now that I know, it seems very obvious and makes a lot of sense!! However I think if you're new to using function pointers then it will cause a bit of confusion - that's why I'm posting an this answer though.